# (ReactNative Curiosity) Why there is line in import component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, import

I am using reactnative and I was curious about the middle line when I import some component like pictures below.
Anyone who knows why? Thx in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CheckBox is deprecated. Looks like you are using Vscode and the tslinter is marking/indicating that import as deprecated.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/checkbox.html

> **Deprecated.** Use `@react-native-community/checkbox` instead.

https://github.com/react-native-checkbox/react-native-checkbox